# screen rotation advice

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android : Save application state on screen orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093213/android-save-application-state-on-screen-orientation-change)

In my app I have a listView. When starts application it automitacally loaded all phone contacts that exists in that phone. So when rotate my phone it's start load again, every time I rotate device it is start reading again and again. What should I do here, so I the contacts load just one time and even I rotate the phone.

Comment: At lest serach for such question once on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093213/android-save-application-state-on-screen-orientation-change/8093272#8093272

Answer (score 4):

```
android:configChanges = "orientation"
```

add this tag in your activity in manifest file.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work I also tried Drax's answer mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

Return the data in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and retrieve it in your `onCreate()` using `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`

If `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` returns null, request the data again.

These two functions are designed to be used to save data between instances of the same activity being recreated because of a configuration change like orientation.

As mentioned, you can alternatively stop Android destroying / recreating your activity on such a configuration change by adding the events you want to manually handle to `android:configChanges = "XXX"` in the activity tag in your manifest. This is suitable if you don't require different assets / layouts etc. when in portrait and landscape.
However, if you only add orientation to configChanges, you might experience the same problem when another event triggers the activity to be recreated - check out: [Handling run time changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a 'Content Provider'. The provider will handle loading and will handle rotaions, onPauses and such. I made a frontend for a spanish digg like page and had the same problem. Here is the project so you can have a look at how you can solve the problem: http://code.google.com/p/meneameandroid/

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add some more to Yashwanth Kumar's ans. like  you need to Override the OnConfigurationChange method in the activity where you are loading the content.

Comment: if you do so. when your device is rotated you will get this method executed first other then any other methods. so you can save your ojects.