# Save data and change orientation

Tags: android, orientation

I have two activities and I use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

```
 @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

          } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

          }
      }
```

One active use for portrait to landscape orientation of the second
**but when the orientation changes, activity is loaded and data is lost**

**How can I save the data and change the activity orientation?**

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915952/how-to-save-state-during-orientation-change-in-android-if-the-state-is-made-of-m

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have small data, you can save and restore it using `onSavedInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` .. for details go through this link [Saving data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

But in case, you have large data then I must say, you should not allow for the orientation changes(which force your activity to recreate). You can restrict it by adding below line in manifest file :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" // fixes orientation
```

Comment: Why do you fixes orientation ? I can not understand

Comment: If a lot of data we'll have a long time to realize onSavedInstanceState or not? or Android will be difficult to process them?

Comment: Maybe large data was a problem for orientation changes in 2012 but at least since 2015 it isn't. I save large data to SQLite when data is created or modified and load it when needed. Orientation change never was a problem with this.

Answer (score 5):

See `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`

Answer (score 4):

I recommend this post

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

to anyone who is still looking for a solution to this problem. The author describes how to use a **Fragment** to retain data.

Make sure to have the call

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

in the `onCreate()` method of your Fragment!

Comment: I think this is a workaround. No solution.

Answer (score 3):

you should check sample application "Multiresolution" here below you can see the snippet of code of "Multiresolution"

```
public final class MultiRes extends Activity {

    private int mCurrentPhotoIndex = 0;
    private int[] mPhotoIds = new int[] { R.drawable.sample_0,
            R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5, R.drawable.sample_6,
            R.drawable.sample_7 };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        showPhoto(mCurrentPhotoIndex);

        // Handle clicks on the 'Next' button.
        Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentPhotoIndex = (mCurrentPhotoIndex + 1)
                        % mPhotoIds.length;
                showPhoto(mCurrentPhotoIndex);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt("photo_index", mCurrentPhotoIndex);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mCurrentPhotoIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("photo_index");
        showPhoto(mCurrentPhotoIndex);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void showPhoto(int photoIndex) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(mPhotoIds[photoIndex]);

        TextView statusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        statusText.setText(String.format("%d/%d", photoIndex + 1,
                mPhotoIds.length));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save any Object by Overriding [public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29)
and calling `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` in your onCreate method.

```
@Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {


    return data;
    }


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    }
```

but if you do this, you have to change your manifest and code, so the normal process for a configuartion change is used.

Different from the SavedInstance method, this only saves the object if the activity is killed because of a configuaration change

Answer (score 0):

The method is `onSaveInstanceState()` and the system calls it when the user is leaving your activity. When the system calls this method, it passes the `Bundle` object that will be saved in the event that your activity is destroyed unexpectedly so you can add additional information to it. Then if the system must recreate the activity instance after it was destroyed, it passes the same `Bundle` object to your activity's `onRestoreInstanceState()` method and also to your `onCreate()`method.

refer to http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html