# how can I save the fragment? when I rotate the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ViewPager and fragments — what's the right way to store fragment's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state)

how can I save the fragment? (It is located at the activity) When I rotate the screen, the activity being restarted, fragment is re-created[image]

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    CustomFragment fragment;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        fragment = (CustomFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("customtag");
    } else {
        fragment = new CustomFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment, "customtag").commit(); 
    }

    ...

}

Comment: by following above code i have posted you can save fragment state.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add **orientation** to **android:configChanges** in your AndroidManifest.xml. Per example:

```
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

Comment: explained to me what does it mean?

Comment: From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html is stated:

_Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called._

Comment: yes it works, but why do people use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState ? maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12214737/1568164

Comment: This looks ugly, but it works great !!!! Thanks.

Comment: The works but I don't recommend it at all. Just expect your that your activity will be recreated. So your onPause() needs to store to permanent storage anything that you need to survive long periods of time, but a rotation will only need you to override onSaveInstanceState and fill out the bundle. 

For fragments specifically for rotations, setRetainInstance(true) will actually handle most of what people will want with regards to behaviour while rotating.

Answer (score 13):

try to use `setRetainInstance(true);` in your fragment's onCreate

Comment: I think this will give me the following - I'll keep all that is in the fragment but I need to save the fragment

Comment: searching I begin to understand that this is something You can add some example