# How to save the data when orientation is changed?

Tags: android

I am using two different layouts for landscape and portrait mode.
In landscape mode, I used scroll view.

I searched and found this solution

```
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

But using this my scroll view is not working.
How to retain data if the data is in spinners.

Comment: remove that line and learn about `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214600/save-data-and-change-orientation

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation explains both `onSaveInstanceState()` and retained Fragments via `setRetainInstance(boolean)`.

For smaller data overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` in the activity is easier. You read your data from the Bundle in `onCreate(Bundle)`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

When orientation is changed, android destroys current activity and create a new one of the same class. And that new activity have its own lifecycle. To save any data - you should override method
[`onSavedInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))
and write parameters to bundle that u get from this method.
To restore any parameters - you can get them from bundle which get when new Activity starts, for example in methods 
[`onCreate(Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))