# Landscape mode, values not persisting

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I am having an Adapter activity that extends `CursorAdapter`. So it has `overriden` methods like `newView()`, `bindView()`. I am updating the viewholder with textview values often. This works good in portrait mode. When turned to landscape mode, the values dont persist.

I know that you need to use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`. But these are for activities and mine is an Adapter class. What do I do in this case?

In a Fragment Activity, I have -

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("Pos", mPosition);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

In my Adapter class,
I have th `viewholder` in `bindview()`. How do I access or use it in Fragment activity and save the values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save data and change orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214600/save-data-and-change-orientation)

Answer (score 1):

Your activity's onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState needs to save all the variable the adapter needs persisted-  either by directly saving them itself, or by adding a function to your adapter to save and restore and calling those.

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I do this? Please see my edited question