# Android - ListView row on[Save|Restore]InstanceState not called

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, screen-orientation

I know that any changes made to a view during runtime are not saved by default of screen rotation. So I persist all changes made to my custom `listview` row in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore them back in `onRestoreInstanceState`. But these methods are not being called at all on screen rotation.

Now I know that views need to have an ID assigned to be persisted across screen rotation. But `ListView` rows are created programmatically in `getView` method of adapter. Does this mean that I need to call `setId` in `getView`?

Comment: The method 'onSaveInstanceState' should be called on screen rotation. Where do you have implemented the method 'onSaveInstanceState'?

Comment: Inside my custom listview row. There is a boolean flag which changes depending on whether the row has been clicked or not and I want to  persist this flag across orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

The `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` have to be implemented in the activity or fragment.

Take a look at [some other post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915952/how-to-save-state-during-orientation-change-in-android-if-the-state-is-made-of-m).